# Sort by occurence

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

Given a list of strings (`arr`) and a character/word (`w`), write a function `s_sort(arr, w)` to sort the list according to the number of times `w` appears in a string of the list.

```py
arr = ['q q q', 'q', 'q q', 'a']
w = 'q'
print(s_sort(arr, w))
```

would give:

```py
['q q q', 'q q', 'q', 'a']
```

and

```py
arr = ['bug', 'bug bug', '#', 'bug bug bug bug']
w = 'bug'
print(s_sort(arr, w))
```

would give:

```py
['bug bug bug bug', 'bug bug', 'bug', '#']
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried first.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
arr = ['bug', 'bug bug', '#', 'bug bug bug bug']
w = 'bug'
out = sorted(arr, key=lambda item: -item.split().count(w))
print(out)  # -> ['bug bug bug bug', 'bug bug', 'bug', '#']
```

Comment: If I have a list containing elements 'win win win' and 'in in' and the given word is 'in' then wouldn't your code sort it as ['win win win', 'in in'] instead of ['in in', 'win win win']? I think it would be better to do this: key= lambda item : -item.split().count(w)

Comment: @Siddhesh They fixed it

Answer (score 1):

```
def s_sort(arr, w):
  def myFunc(e):
    return e.split(" ").count(w)
  
  arr.sort(key=myFunc, reverse=True)
  return arr
```

The code above should work.

Comment: It would not work for `arr = ['q q q', 'q a b c d e', 'q q', 'a']`. If I understand the problem correct.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis i edited it to take care of `w` parameter. Nice catch.

Comment: Sorting a list in-place and returning it is generally bad practice. Do one or the other -- probably better to return it, to keep the function pure. As well, you can use a `lambda` instead of a `def`, and you don't need to provide an argument to `str.split()`. So: `def s_sort(arr, w): return sorted(arr, key=lambda e: e.split().count(w), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 1):

The current answers only work if you have the same word in the `arr`. Here is code that works for any items in the `arr`:

```
def fn(arr,w):
    ord_lst = []
    for x in arr:
        ord_lst.append(x.count(w))
    return [x for _,x in sorted(zip(ord_lst,arr),reverse=True)]

arr = ['bug', 'bug bug', '# c c c c c c c', 'bug bug bug bug']
w = 'bug'
fn(arr,w)
# ['bug bug bug bug', 'bug bug', 'bug', '# c c c c c c c']
```

Comment: I tried your example with the two other answers (both posted / last edited before yours) and they get the correct result.

Comment: You can use a sort key to simplify this massively: `def fn(arr, w): return sorted(arr, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x.count(w))`